# How can I get multiple numbers from a user and add even numbers together and multiply odd numbers?

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that takes 5 inputs and adds even numbers and multiplies odd numbers, but I do not know how to do this after I know which number is odd and which is even.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   
 int a, b, c, d, e, sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5, sum6, sum7, sum8, sum9, sum10;
    
    cout<<"Please Enter 5 Integers\t:\t";
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
    
    if(a%2==0 && b%2==0)
    {
        cout<<a+b;
        sum1 = a+b;
    }
    
    if(a%2==0 && c%2==0)
    {
        cout<<a+c;
        sum2 = a+c;
    }
    
    if(a%2==0 && d%2==0)
    {
        cout<<a+d;
        sum3 = a+d;
    }
    
    if(a%2==0 && e%2==0)
    {
        cout<<a+e;
        sum4 = a+e;
    }
    
    if(b%2==0 && c%2==0)
    {
        cout<<b+c;
        sum5 = b+c;
    }
    
    if(b%2==0 && d%2==0)
    {
        cout<< b+d;
        sum6 = b+d;
    }
    
    if(b%2==0 && e%2==0)
    {
        cout<<b+e;
        sum7 = b+e;
    }
    
    if(c%2==0 && d%2==0)
    {
        cout<< c+d;
        sum8 = c+d;
    }
    
    if(c%2==0 && e%2==0)
    {
        cout<<c+e;
        sum9 = c+e;
    }
    
    if(d%2==0 && e%2==0)
    {
        cout<<d+e;
        sum10 = d+e;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code ?!?

Comment: It looks like you're testing all possible combinations for even numbers, It looks like a cumbersome way to do it, but ... should work if you do it for odd numbers too. Do you have a plan to present the `sum`s too?

Comment: Side note: when you find yourself making sequentially named variables like `a, b, c, d, e` or `sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5, sum6, sum7, sum8, sum9, sum10` you've probably found a task where using an array will make the job a lot easier.

Comment: Arrays and loops make this a lot smaller and easier to manage.

Comment: Hi guys!Thank you for your suggestions ! I am at the first of way for writing an applicatin! and I don't have a lot of information for that ! Thans a lot

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all of those variables, and you certainly do not need to check every combination of variables one at a time.  A simple loop will suffice.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   
    int number, sum = 0, product = 1;
    
    cout << "Please Enter 5 Integers\t:\t";

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cin >> number;
    
        if (number % 2 == 0)
            sum += number;
        else
            product *= number;
    }
    
    cout << sum << ' ' << product << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't name that variable `sum2` because it is not a sum. :)

Comment: @Devolus yes, I just realized that, updated.

Comment: Everybody needs `sum1`, but `sum2`... that's optional.

Comment: HI to all!Thank you for your suggestions ... In addition your attention !

Answer (score 3):

This is a very rough and relatively simple solution. It throws an exception if the input is not convertible to an int. And since the exception is not caught anywhere, the program exits if the user enters invalid input.

`std::vector` is roughly the same as an array. It spares you from having to declare 5 variables, and instead stores all the input values in the vector.

The `stoi()` function converts a string to an integer (stoi = **s**tring **to** **i**nteger).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    bool outputSum, outputProduct = false;
    std::vector<int> input;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::string entered_string;
        int entered_value = 0;
        std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        std::cin>>entered_string;
        entered_value = stoi(entered_string);
        input.emplace_back(entered_value);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (input[i] % 2 == 0) {
            sum += input[i];
            outputSum = true;
        } else {
            product *= input[i];
            outputProduct = true;
        }
    }
    if (outputSum) {
        std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    if (outputProduct) {
        std::cout << "Product: " << product << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am assuming that you do not want to add the sum and the product at the end, since you didn't specify what exactly you want your output to be.

Comment: Why are you reading the user's input into a `string` first and then converting that to an `int`, instead of just reading into an `int` to begin with? If you want an exception thrown on bad input, you can enable [`cin.exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding of loops makes this code very simple. You store the five numbers, but they're disconnected from each other since they're stored in separate variables. Now you have to write the many tests that you have, and it's a big mess and you feel like there has to be an easier way.

As other answers show, if you don't need to use the numbers later, then you don't need five variables for input; one is sufficient. You store the input into a variable, check if it's even/odd, and update the sum or product variable accordingly. The repetition of a loop makes this work.

If you need to display the numbers or otherwise keep them around for other purposes, an array (or `std::vector` in this case) comes in handy.

The code below demonstrates a C++ Standard Library function ([`std::reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)) that can generate the sum or the product. Other answers do a fine job showing how to calculate those values manually. And just to re-iterate, this solution would be considered viable only if you needed the numbers for some other task.

```cpp
#include <functional>  // std::multiplies
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>  // std::reduce
#include <vector>

void print_container(std::vector<int> v) {
  for (auto i : v) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  constexpr int numInputs = 5;

  std::vector<int> evenNums;
  std::vector<int> oddNums;

  for (int tmp, i = 0; i < numInputs && std::cin >> tmp; ++i) {
    tmp & 1 ? oddNums.push_back(tmp) : evenNums.push_back(tmp);
  }

  int sum = std::reduce(evenNums.begin(), evenNums.end(), 0);
  int product = std::reduce(oddNums.begin(), oddNums.end(), 1,
                                std::multiplies<int>());

  std::cout << "Even numbers: ";
  print_container(evenNums);
  std::cout << "Odd numbers: ";
  print_container(oddNums);
  std::cout << "Sum of evens: " << sum << "\nProduct of odds: " << product << '\n';
}
```

Output (with input being 1 2 3 4 5):

```
Even numbers: 2 4 
Odd numbers: 1 3 5 
Sum of evens: 6
Product of odds: 15
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your advice ! Again and again thank you